# Why does my loop start output from 4?

Tags: python

I know that using of it probably make no sense, but I'm interested in why it works this way.
Why it starts from 4 ? Why it doesn't include 10 ? Why we are out of range ?

```
n=[2, 3, 4, 7, 9, 10]
for a in n:
    print (n[a])
```

---

```
Output

4
7
9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PyPro\new1.py", line 3, in <module>
    print (n[a])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: hint: try `for a in n: print(a)`

Comment: Have you traced through the code by hand or with a debugger? Do you understand how for loops work? Do you understand how array indexing works?

Comment: I know how loops ans lists work. it is not my purpose to print all elements of lists. I want to understand why it works like it does. Just for fun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when you place something inside square brackets of a list it refers to the position of the element in the list.

In your example:

```
n=[2, 3, 4, 7, 9, 10]
for a in n:  ## Here 'a' refers to list element
    print (n[a])   ## Here 'a' refers to position of element
```

Iteration 1:

a is first element of list n, therefore a = 2

but when you print you write a as a position because a = 2, therefore it refers to position 3 (in python index starts from 0, thus 0 , 1, 2)

hence n[2] which is equal to 4 is printed

Similarly
n[3], n[4], n[7], n[9] and n[10] should be printed.

But because index in n is upto 5 you get an error at n[7]

So output is :

```
4   ##print (n[2])*
7   ##print (n[3])*
9   ##print (n[4])*
```

*Only for explanation, not the actual output

Comment: Weird and useles method to reverse list (wich are sorted from bigger to lower, and withtout gaps=)))))

n=[5,4,3,2,1,0]
for a in n:
 print (n[a])

Answer (score 1):

So when you do

```
for a in n:
```

the a variable will be the elements in your list so 2,3,4,7,9,10 in that order

So if you wanted to print from your list you would do

```
for a in n:
    print(a)
```

Or you could do

```
for a in range(len(a)):
    print(n[a])
```

In this case a will be 0,1,2,3,4,5

Comment: I know how to print all elements of a list. I wonder why my code works like this.

Answer (score 0):

you are using the value as an index.
so instead of going through the range 0,1,2,3,4,5...
you are going through indexes number: 2, 3, 4, 7 which goes out of range.
it should be:

```
for a in n:
    print(a)
```